# How to use ant-design-pro components in ant-design react app?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I have created react app with create-react-app and used ant-design components, as the project becomes bigger, I need to use some awesome components from ant-design-pro.

Is there any way to integrate ant-design-pro components in existing ant-design project?

I have tried to import and use @ant-design/pro-layout but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For V4 refer to [Upgrade to V4](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro-site/edit/master/docs/upgrade-v4.en-US.md), check [Replace BasicLayout](https://pro.ant.design/docs/upgrade-v4#replace-basiclayout) if you use `@ant-design/pro-layout`.

For single components use `npm install ant-design-pro@2.3.2` and import components for your needs:

`import Ellipsis from 'ant-design-pro/lib/Ellipsis';`

Demo:

[image: Edit OS Q 56488542]

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is what I want

Comment: Do you need the less-loader to import antd pro component?

Comment: I got this error 

```
./node_modules/antd/es/typography/style/index.less 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> @import '../../style/themes/index';
| @import '../../style/mixins/index';
| 
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

It seems that the `ant-design` team chose to integrate `ant-design-pro` components directly into `antd`.
The version `2.3.0` of `ant-design-pro` was the latest version of the library that you could use as a component library. (source: their [changelog](https://pro.ant.design/docs/changelog#230)).

You can probably still install that version ([here's the documentation](https://v2-pro.ant.design/docs/use-components-alone) to do so).

They recently released the v4 of `ant-design-pro` and I'm not entirely sure whether you can install the components stand-alone or not.

However, a lot of components from `ant-design-pro` are now maintained directly inside `ant design`, as you can see [here](https://v2-pro.ant.design/docs/changelog#220):

> In the next version of Pro, we will gradually remove all the components that will be added to the Ant Design, which are under development:
>
> ...
>
> These components will be more fully supported and maintained in Ant Design, and Pro will focus on Layout and scaffolding.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. It's helpful.

Comment: Can I use ant design pro component without less-loader