# How to include ant design pro components in existing react component

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Sorry if this knowledge is already online, I am having a hard time finding the right resources so any help would be appreciated.

I have an existing web page made using react.js, and I want to use a component from ant-pro. I have used previous components from ant, but I managed to do so by importing them. This component only seems to be part of ant-pro. The link is below.

https://preview.pro.ant.design/editor/flow

I have tried using the below help by copying in the flow editor to the node modules but I just get the error

[How to use ant-design-pro components in ant-design react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488542/how-to-use-ant-design-pro-components-in-ant-design-react-app)

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| GGEditor.setTrackable(false);
| export default () => (
>   <PageHeaderWrapper
|     content={formatMessage({
|       id: 'editorandflow.description',
'.
```

Also my project does not use the ant-design architecture.

The only other thing I changed was the import to

`import Flow from 'ant-design-pro/lib/flow';`

Thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your import code and other relevant code?

Comment: @JayCodist okay done